# jQuery blur not working on page load

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of jQuery...

```
$('.group-guest-list input.form-text').blur(function() {
  if(!$.trim(this.value).length) {
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

It checks to see if a text input is empty, and adds a "disabled" class if it is.

This only works if you click inside the field, and then click out again. On the first page load, the class isnt there. I need it to react on blur so that when the field is emptied it is disabled.

Can someone help to make this run on page load, as well as on focus? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind multiple events using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to execute the event handler on page load.

```
$('.group-guest-list input.form-text').on('blur focus', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('disabled', !$.trim(this.value).length);
}).trigger('blur');
```

Additionally, You can use  [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)

Comment: I'm getting an error... Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list -

Comment: Ah! There we go, thats awesome. Thank you! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if page loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.group-guest-list input.form-text').blur(function() {
  if(!$.trim(this.value).length) {
    $(this).closest('div').addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass('disabled');
  }
});

});
```

Comment: yeah its in a doc ready function, i just didnt include that in the question because this is part of a larger script. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into events once the DOM is loaded. Like this:

```
$(function() {
    function onTxtFocusChanged() {
        if(!$.trim(this.value).length) {
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass('disabled');
      }
  }

  $('.txt').on('blur focus', function() {
      onTxtFocusChanged.call(this);
  });
});
```